# Loading jQuery in Wordpress backend getting error: "jQuery is not defined"

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm in the backend of Wordpress, trying to create a metabox. I put this code at the top of the metabox so that I can use some jQuery to create it:

```
if (is_admin()){
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

I am getting a "jQuery is not defined" error. I tried changing it to the $ as well, and get the same error - "$ is not defined"

**EDIT:** My actual jQuery code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add_person').click(function(){      
            $('#management').append('<div class="person"><a href="#" class="remove_person button">Remove Person</a>' + '<p><label for="_name">Name</label><br/>' + '<input type="text" id="_name" name="_name[]" size="25" /></p></div>');
            return false;
        });
        $('.remove_person').live('click',function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why is this happening? I checked in developer (chrome extension) and jQuery is listed as a resource so it is recognizing it, but am still getting this error. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right place to deregister and re-enqueue it? Also: since jQuery is already included in the back end, is there a particular reason you want to re-register the google APIs version? Why not use the built in one? In any event, using Developer (or whatever other tool), make sure jQuery isn't included twice.

Comment: Well, the reason I put that code there in the first place is because I was always getting that error ("jQuery is not defined"). I thought perhaps registering it in the backend would help, but still am getting the error anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing jquery.min.js in the resources area, and you are getting a `jQuery is undefined error`, that typically means that jQuery is being included farther down the page than your code.

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery anywhere else in my code. Where else would it be called in the backend?

Comment: The only way I was able to see the jquery.min.js in resources is by adding that code above in my example

Comment: Look at the html of the page and find your script, then find jQuery script. Does the jQuery script come first, or does yours. (view source)

Comment: My jQuery came first before everything, I accidentally placed it outside of a function and it put it at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FTP into your site and open up your wp-config.php file.

Add this line:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Make sure you add this before:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Hopefully this helps you save the day for your WordPress installs!